# Pause Bash loop

Tags: bash, loops

I have the following Bash script. How can I make it pause on keypress or pause after a number of loops, but if I don't press any key it should loop?

```
for i in `cat files` 
do
    echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I initially misread your question. You can suspend the active process at any time by pressing `Ctrl+Z`, and resume it with the [fg](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html#SEC34) builtin.

In order to make the script pause after a number of iterations have been performed, you can use a counter variable and the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator `%`:

```
i=1
for f in `cat files`; do
    echo $f
    if (( i % 10 == 0 )); then  # pause every 10 iterations
        read
    fi
    let "i++"
done
```

---

My original answer was:

You can use the [read](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html) builtin to have the shell wait until the user presses the `RETURN` key (or the `EOF` key, `Ctrl+D`):

```
for i in `cat files`
do
    echo $i
    read
done
```

You can use the `-t` option of `read` in order have it time out and continue execution:

```
for i in `cat files`
do
    echo $i
    read -t 1
done
```

The above will resume execution after 1 second if the user doesn't press the `RETURN` key.

Comment: this make the script wait for anykey to start each-loop-tick

Comment: @newmusicblog, no, it won't. Then again, you just added that requirement to your question :)

Comment: if i use this script, it only echoes one variable and then it waits ||| i need it to loop indifinetly untill i press pause

Comment: yeah that's great, it works. Aside from that any ideea how to make it stop after a number of loops ?